# Graphics clipping: How can repeated half-space clipping fail?

Tags: convex-analysis, computational-geometry

Hi I am currently going through the past exam problems and I am stuck on this clipping problem. Could you give me some hint on how to solve it?

> If we clip a polygon to a window, it is inadequate to merely perform repeated half-space clipping on each polygon line segment independently. Give an example illustrating why independent clipping of polygon line segments may fail to correctly clip a convex polygon. A picture alone is inadequate; you should also give a short answer describing the picture and why it illustrates the problem, noting both the incorrectly clipped polygon and what the correctly clipped polygon should be.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If you were clipping a polygon to a single half-space, such as the set of points $(x,y)$ with $y>0$, then repeated half-space clipping would work. In order to come up with an example where the procedure fails, the polygon will have to interact with at least two different sides of the window...

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem means by repeated half-space clipping.

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, but I gather from related questions that it's the following procedure: For each edge, clip it against each of the four half-spaces that bound the window. The edge will either be untouched, or it will shrink, or it will be discarded. After this is done to each edge, there may be gaps in the polygon, so they're simply filled in with new line segments. ...Now, this might not be what the instructor of that course intended, but for practice purposes I think it's a reasonable procedure to consider.

Comment: I have just tested the algorithm you described, and it does seem to have problems when clipped against two boundaries. The object I used was a cube, one of the lines extended beyond the boundaries. I don't quite understand what is going on, do you have a simple example to show why this happened?

Comment: I have added a picture of the phenomenon.

Comment: Oh, I think this was supposed to be a 2D problem! But that works. I had the same idea in mind: Place the polygon around one of the corners of the window. Then the proper clipping would place a vertex at the corner, but our naive procedure fails to do so.

Comment: But even if the algorithm fail to place a vertex at the corner wouldn't the polygon still be clipped correctly. That is I still won't see the parts that are off boundary right?

Comment: I don't think so. Suppose the window is $0<x<2$ and $0<y<2$, and our polygon is the square $(1,1),(3,1),(3,3),(1,3)$. Upon independently clipping each edge, only two edges survive: $(1,1),(2,1)$ and $(1,2),(1,1)$. If we join these together, we get the triangle $(1,1),(2,1),(1,2)$. But the correct clipping would have been the square $(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(1,2)$.

Comment: What if I don't join the two points that make a triangle? Wouldn't that still work?

Comment: Well, then you don't have a polygon at all, do you? Just a random collection of line segments. You could stroke it as a path, but that's about it. You wouldn't be able to use it as an input to further algorithms that expect a true polygon, like hit testing.

Comment: I see what you mean, I guess the image I showed you might be the phenomenon you described. I thought if that I could just leave out the line segments that are not within the viewport.